# Scroll to the top of page when starts to type in a input

Tags: javascript, jquery

The page can be see on [www.toyopar.com.br/estoque](http://www.toyopar.com.br/estoque) (mobile version)
It have a stick input, and I need to scroll to the top when someone start to type on input. The result cannot been seen if you dont scroll to the top.

I'm using the code below but it doesnt work.

```
$("#busca-seminovo-2").test.on('keyup input', function(){
  $("#carros-resultado").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to find what's wrong when using mobile, since the input is in the top, won't it go to top too?

Comment: It is all working for me, in Chrome for Android. Please note that your question could be considered as a promotion.